# DataGrid validation display error problem

Tags: silverlight, validation, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I have a little problem with the silverlight data grid. I wrote a little sample app to show the problem. (You can download it here: http://rapidshare.com/files/433480041/DataGridValidationTest.zip). 
Here you can Add a new Person (has a Name and an Age) to a Collection which is displayed in a DataGrid.
 I also implemented the validation based on the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface. If you click save, the data is validatet (Name must not be null, Age gt 0). 
 
The validation works fine, but the validation errors are only displayed if I click into one row. After clicking the Save Button, the data is validatet, but not shown in the grid (see picture below): 
[image: Validation is not shown :(]

If I click in the row, to change the data, the validation message is shown (picture below):
[image: Validation shown]

If I'm in that row, I have to resolve the problem, cause I'm not able to select another cell.

Does anyone know, how I can show (all) errors directly in the grid?
And can I get out of the cell with the error without resolving the problem?

Thx in advance,

TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, in Silverlight datagrid, only one row would be active at a time, so if you want to valudate all rows at the same time, it is not possible.

Another workaround is add your all content in the same cell. So all your data would be editable and it would be validated at the same time as well. What I mean is

If you have grid with 2 columns -

`<DataGrid>
<Name>
<Age>
</DataGrid>`

make it look like this
`<Grid>
<Cell>
<Grid>
<Name>
<Age>
</Grid>
</Cell></DataGrid>`